# Train Amazon SageMaker object detection model on local PC

Tags: amazon-sagemaker, training-data, custom-training

I wonder if it's possible to run training Amazon SageMaker object detection model on a local PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably referring to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object-detection.html) object detection algorithm which is part of of [Amazon SageMaker built-in algorithms](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/algos.html). **Built-in algorithms must be trained on the cloud**.
If you're bringing your own Tensorflow or PyTorch model, you could use SageMaker training jobs to train either on the cloud or locally as @kirit noted.

I would also look at [SageMaker JumpStart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-jumpstart.html) for a wide variety of object detection algorithm which are TF/PT based.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SageMaker Local Mode to run SageMaker training jobs locally on your PC. Here is a list of examples. https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-local-mode